# Unable to resolve the source file on Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to clone the copy of magento 2 to other domain. Somehow i was managed to run it on other domain but style is missing and 1 resource file i did checked in source file is not loading.

```
https://dev.xxxx.com/pub/static/version1580225023/frontend/Devetc/webber/nb_NO/css/styles.css
```

And following is showing when accessing this above URL

```
#0 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/dev.xxxx.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php(121): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/dev.xxxx.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/dev.xxxx.com/pub/static.php(13): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource))
#3 {main}
```

Cannot get applied style to theme on magento 2.